# PC doesn't POST (no beep code at all) but lights and fans on - If I remove RAM I do get "no RAM" beep code

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, hardware-failure, post

The title explains a lot but I'll try and explain more what has been happening here.

I turned on my PC yesterdays normal and it went straight to windows 10 bluescreen with stop code 0xC000021A (STATUS_SYSTEM_PROCESS_TERMINATED). I let it get to 100% and restart and it went straight back into the same blue screen.

I let it restart again into Automatic Repair which did nothing (as usual) and then took me to the recovery center (whatever it is called). I tried to boot into safe mode but got the same 0xC000021A BSOD. Next time it did Automatic Repair it decided to scan C:\ but this just got to 100% and then restarted back to the same BSOD.

Next time I got to the recovery center I oppened Command Prompt and ran `chkdsk /r` and `sfc /scannow`, both didn't report any issues with my SSDs. Restarted and got the BSOD again.

I tried to Reset PC 'Keep My Files' option and after about 20s of "getting things ready" it just stops telling me it couldn't reset my pc.

I really don't want to have to do a clean install because I did some quite important work on it the evening before and stupidly didn't run my backup before shutting down for the night.

So, I created a Windows 10 bootable USB using [this link to the official site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10). I booted off the USB and choose 'Repair an Installation' (paraphrasing), I ran `chkdsk /r` and `sfc /scannow` on C:\ drive from there in case it makes a difference to run it from the USB if that makes sense, again no issues found.

I couldn't find anything else in the bootable USB's recovery center that would help. Automatic Repair did nothing and there was no choice to reset pc (I guess because I was wasn't running the recovery center from the drive with a Win10 installation?). I thought by having a recovery USB, the recovery center would have the option to repair the corrupted boot files in my Win10 installation? Is that not something that can be done?

Anyway, I thought I'd strip the PC of anything not needed so I'm left with just the motherboard, CPU, PSU, GPU and RAM. I booted up, same BSOD. I thought I'd make sure it wasn't a hardware issue so I re-seated the GPU and the RAM. Same BSOD.

**Then I removed one stick of RAM and this is where it got weird.** No POST, no beep codes, nothing. So I switched the sticks (I only have 2 sticks so I replaced the single one with the other one I had removed), same thing, no POST, no beep code. The lights are on the motherboard, the fans start up when I press power but it doesn't POST.

I decided to remove both RAM sticks to see if that would do anything and thankfully I got the beep code that means "no RAM detected". I put both sticks back in and again, no POST, no beep code.

I tried googling around for this scenario but I could only find people saying that the lights are on, fans are on but they get no POST or beep codes **if they have RAM in the motherboard AS WELL AS if they remove all RAM**. This is different to my situation because I am getting the correct 'no RAM' beep code when I remove RAM but nothing when either or both t sticks are in.

Does anyone have any advice or have been in this position themselves? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a system failure to me.
First you should rebuild the files responsible for booting the OS.
Open a command prompt and type the following:

- bootrec /fixMBR
- bootrec /fixBoot
- bootrec /rebuildBCD

If you still can't boot after this, then there is a another solution that I haven't tried yet, but should do the trick.

**Troubleshoot/ Advanced Options/ Startup Settings** and click **Restart**. You'll see some options, you have to press the number of the **Disable Driver Signature option** (7 I think).

Comment: I don't know if this makes any sense at all, but what if OP has GPT instead of MBR?

Comment: @Rattlehead Thanks for the info. I reseated the RAM and GPU and it started working again but still just POSTing and booting into the BSOD. I tried those in Cmd Prompt in the Recovery area, they just said they completed successfully but made no difference to the BSOD. I was able to pull all my files off the SSD and do a clean install. Very frustrating but I had spent 2 days trying to sort it out. It seems crazy to me that if I have a recovery bootable USB, that it can't just repair the boot files on the SSD from that USB and I have to do a complete reformat/re-install. Anyway, thanks again!